# Composed object needs access to parent class method

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

I have a class `Round` that has a `Calc` composed class object. `Round` also inherits from several base classes, and inherits a method called `parameter` from one of its base classes.

`Calc` has a method, `compute`, that is called from a method in `Round`, using:

```
self.calc_object.compute(...)
```

This `compute` method, however, needs access to `parameter`, and we cannot change the API of `compute`, but we can change the api of `Calc's` constructor, so I was thinking of passing in `self.parameter` when constructing `self.calc_object = Calc(self.parameter, other args)`. Is this a valid approach? Are there other approaches I should consider?

The solution needs to work for both python2 and python3.

Comment: You could pass the entire `self` object as a parameter to `Calc()`, then it can access any attributes it may eventually need.

Comment: @Barmar I see, but if it only needs `parameter`, then is it better to just pass in `self.parameter` instead of the entirety of `self`?

Comment: You can certainly do that. It's just not as easily extended in the future.